# Quarkus EventBus requestandforget - timeout error in logs

Tags: quarkus

When trying to use *Quarkus* (version 2.9.2.Final) *EventBus* `requestAndForget` with a `@ConsumeEvent` method that returns **void**, the following exception occurs in the logs, even though the processing occurs without any problem.

> OK
>
> 2022-06-07 09:44:04,064 ERROR [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure]
> (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Mutiny had to drop the following
> exception: (TIMEOUT,-1) Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply.
> address: __vertx.reply.3, repliedAddress: receivedSomeEvent

The consumer code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConsumerManiac{
  @ConsumeEvent(value = "receivedSomeEvent")
  public void consume(SomeEvent someEvent ) {

    System.out.println("OK");
  }
}
```

The Producer code (a REST Endpoint):

```
public class SomeResource {
  private final EventBus eventBus;

  @Inject
  public SomeResource (EventBus eventBus) {

    this.eventBus = eventBus;
  }

  @POST
  public Response send(@Valid SomeEvent someEvent) {

    eventBus.requestAndForget("receivedSomeEvent", someEvent);

    return Response.accepted().build();
  }
}
```

If the consumer method is changed to return some value, then the exception in logs does not occur.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConsumerManiac{
  @ConsumeEvent(value = "receivedSomeEvent")
  public String consume(SomeEvent someEvent ) {

    System.out.println("OK");

   return "ok";
  }
}
```

Is there any missing piece of code that is missing so the exception does not occur (even though processing concludes without any problem)?

*Reference*: https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-event-bus#implementing-fire-and-forget-interactions

Full stacktrace:

> 2022-06-07 09:44:04,064 ERROR [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure]
> (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Mutiny had to drop the following
> exception: (TIMEOUT,-1) Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply.
> address: __vertx.reply.3, repliedAddress: receivedSomeEvent at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.ReplyHandler.handle(ReplyHandler.java:76)
> at
> io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.ReplyHandler.handle(ReplyHandler.java:24)
> at
> io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:893)
> at
> io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:860)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:50)
> at
> io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.emit(DuplicatedContext.java:168)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.emit(AbstractContext.java:53)
> at
> io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.run(VertxImpl.java:883)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)     at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

documentation is not correct.

request expect a response. You want to use send and not request.

see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/31045

Comment: Found as much! I tested with send() and it worked. Like, eventBus.send("myAddress", null)

Answer (score 1):

I had to return arbitrary value to avoid this exception.

Comment: That is already stated in the question.